# How to remove leading 0 from a string with space in between in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I know how to remove the leading 0 if it does not have any space in between

```
var strVal = "000001234";
strVal.TrimStart('0');
```

will give result "1234".
But i am not sure what to do with

```
var strVal ="0000 00001234";
```

I tried:

```
strVal.Trim().TrimStart('0');
```

but it returned "00001234".
Can anyone please help.

Comment: `strVal.TrimStart(' ', '0');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify more than one character to remove from the start of the string when you call `TrimStart`, so you can simply include the space character:

```
"00 00123".TrimStart(' ', '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

`Trim` wouldn't work because it:

> Removes all **leading** and **trailing** white-space characters from the current String object.

It does not remove anything "inside" the string.

As an alternative to Rufus L's solution, here's a solution with regex:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// ...

Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(strVal, "^[0\\s]+", ""));
```

Explanation:

- `^`: start of string
- `[]`: match any one thing inside the brackets
- `\\s`: match any whitespace
- `+` repeat this 1 or more times